# Pulling Data Across Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am struggling with a formula in google sheets to pull TRUE/FALSE in column J of PracticeTracker sheet in the google doc link given below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qEPxMYm1_DvKheg0klIgqrzy9Glhbo8LCyg5ducrswA/edit#gid=1142572750
Column J has tick boxes and i want to compare the student ID in column D and date in row 4 with the data in HW sheet column B and column D. If student with ID in column D (PracticeTracker sheet) has submitted the homework on that date (means student ID appears in HW sheet on that date), value in column J should be TRUE else it should be false. TRUE value will automatically tick the checkbox in there. that is what i finally want.
Looking forward for help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=vstack("Homework",
    map($D6:$D,lambda(d,let(Σ,ifna(filter(HW!$B:$B,HW!$B:$B=d,HW!$D:$D=H4)),if(len(Σ),true,false)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution but it is not what is required. Actually the start date in column E has nothing to do with the whole stuff. Dates are in row 4 (first date appears in H4, second on K4 and so on). if the student with ID in column D submitted the home work on corresponding date in row 4, then we need the check box to be ticked. homework submission status by that ID on that date is in HW sheet. Hope i made this clear

Comment: Updated the formula to look at the data headers in `row_4` instead of start_date column

Comment: Yeah its working and Thanks for your help. The formula is too complex for me to understand but its working seamlessly.